# PHP Division By Zero?

Tags: php, curl

Two hours ago the following script worked. Now for some reason, I'm getting an error "Warning: Division by zero in _ on line 30". Here's the script. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it?

Basically this script is pulling data from two elements on another website, dividing them to get a number which in turn is being used to set the width of an element. Been troubleshooting this for a while. Thanks so much in advance!

```
<?php
define("FFF_SIXDEGREES", "http://www.stayclassy.org/fundraise?fcid=257739");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, FFF_SIXDEGREES);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

if(!($results = curl_exec($curl))) {
    print("{ \"total\": \"$0.00\" }");
    return;
}

$pattern = '/<li class="goalTitle">Raised so far:<\/li>\s*<li>\$([\d\.,]+)<\/li>/';
preg_match($pattern, $results, $matches);

$total = $matches[1];
$total = str_replace(",", "", $total);

// printf("<h2 class=\"raised-total\">$%s</h2>", formatMoney($total, true));

$pattern2 = '/<li class="goalTitle">My goal:<\/li>\s*<li>\$([\d\.,]+)<\/li>/';
preg_match($pattern2, $results, $matches);

$total2 = $matches[1];
$total2 = str_replace(",", "", $total2);

// printf("<h2 class=\"goal-total\">$%s</h2>", formatMoney($total2, true));

$diff = ($total/$total2) * 100; // THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE IN QUESTION

function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) 
{
    if ($fractional) {
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
    }
    while (true) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
} 
echo "<div class=\"progress-header\" style=\"width:$diff%;\"><span class=\"raised-amount\">$$total</span><span class=\"goal-amount\">$$total2</span></div>";
```

?>

Comment: It generally helps to provide the line of code as well. Very few will go and count the lines in your code....

Comment: Could you mark the line? I don't want to count...

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that it's the only line with a division. `$diff = ($total/$total2) * 100;` Apparently `$total2` is 0.

Comment: I can see you're dividing by `$total2`. Is it possible that it's empty?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the quick responses. If you go to the address, http://www.stayclassy.org/fundraise?fcid=257739, "$total2" is pulling the number under "My goal" on that website which is $1000. I don't understand why I'd be getting a value of 0.

Comment: @Noah Check my answer, it should give you idea why are you receiving 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$total2` is `0` because you set wrong RegExp.

First, add `i` after last `/` in both patterns to change mode to case insensitive (you've got eg. `Raised So Far` on website but you're using `Raised so far`). Next, check what are you getting in your both `$matches`.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is helpfull here. On that line:

```
$diff = ($total/$total2) * 100;
```

the $total2 variable maybe sometime equal to 0, so php cannot execute the calculation (it's impossible to divide by zero). So you chould do somthing like this :

```
if($total2) // This condition will be true if $total2 != 0
    $diff = ($total/$total2) * 100;
else
    $diff = 0;
```

Also, I can see on your code that $total and $total2 are string, converted into float. This can be a source of error too. You should force the conversion to float using floatval :

```
if(floatval($total2))
    $diff = ( floatval($total) / floatval($total2) ) * 100;
else
    $diff = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you go to the address, stayclassy.org/fundraise?fcid=257739, "$total2" is pulling the number under "My goal" on that website which is $1000. I don't understand why I'd be getting a value of 0. Here's the production site: http://funforfreedom.com

Comment: Just before `$total2 = $matches[1];` please enter this line `print_r($matches); die();` and paste the result here.

Comment: i checked your page. You should add 'i'at the end of your RegExps to ensure that the test is not case sensitive. And then, you will see with the print_r above if your $total2 variable contains the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it is actually only a warning and doesn't cause the script to stop, you can also use the following to simply hush the messages on that line:

```
<?php

    $var=4;
    $diff = (100/$var) * 100;
    echo $diff."<br><br>";

    $var=0;
    $diff = (100/$var) * 100;
    echo $diff."<br><br>";

    $var=0;
    $diff = @(100/$var) * 100; // Note the @ symbol before the possible wanring
    echo $diff."<br><br>";

?>
```

Output:

```
2500

Warning: Division by zero in C:\Server\www\test1.php on line 8
0

0
```

Basically, it will render as a zero. It's not the best way, but in terms of efficiency, if you are dealing with a lot of data, it might be better to not display the warning as compared to performing validation on each row of data.

It's probably not what I would do (though I have done it once) but I thought I would offer it as a suggestion.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the response. It's actually not spitting out data. If you go here, you can see it: http://www.funforfreedom.com/

Comment: @Noah how is it relevant if it is spitting out data or not? You can still use the suggestion given here.